# Apache apachectl/httpd hangs

Tags: apache-2.2, oracle-11g

[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle11g/111060_linuxsoft.html) HTTP Server (OHS), RHEL 5.3, Dell hardware

Oracle has a modified version of Apache2  for use with web-enabled components in its product suite. The **apachectl start** command just hangs, even *configtest* hangs! Not sure what it is waiting for. How does one go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

strace -f apachectl start

and see what the last dozen lines or so are trying to do. The output is a little bit crazy, so you might update your question with the output, and maybe someone can help.

Comment: It was waiting on a read from /dev/random. That led me to do some googling on Linux, entropy pool and the like and the problem is now solved. Thanks for the tip, never would have guessed.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :-)

Comment: Wow, super. You're sharper than a sack of wet mice, that's for sure. =)

Comment: Thanks, had a problem starting apache and used this to find out it was network drive mounting issues